# Communicate with default Email client (AIDL)

Tags: android, email, android-source, aidl

Is it possible to add existing email account to default android emaill app from my application? In a repository we can see some `AIDL` files [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/tree/master/emailcommon/src/com/android/emailcommon/service), 
but I can't see any method like `addAccount`.
 
Also, every release those `AIDL` files are a little bit different. Can I somehow add an account to email client? Or is there any application that allows a developer to do that using `AIDL`? It has to support POP, IMAP and EAS(ActiveSync).

Comment: Can you please explain more about the specific  **one** problem you're currently facing?

Comment: I have to add Email account without user interaction (POP/IMAP/EAS). I'm wondering if I can do it without creating my own Email client (K-9 is using WebDav - that is bad). Now I'm trying to build AOSP Email application, but I think that is pointless.

Comment: Are you building a custom version of Android or are you trying to add an account to a Google distributed OS which is running the Email application?

Comment: Now, I'm trying to compile AOSP Email application, and then modify it, and distribute as new app (Apache 2 license). I'm working on it, but I don't know if it is possible... Is it?